# Can I call restrict(amp) callable explicitly, ensuring it will run on accelerator

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gpu, c++-amp

I have:

```
void foo() restrict(amp)
{
}
```

Now if I do:

```
void main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Will it run on accelerator? If no, how to run `foo()` in accelerator without using `parallel_for_each` loop?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh388953.aspx): `A function that does not have a restrict clause is the same as a function that has the restrict(cpu) clause.` So no, it won't run on an AMP-accelerated device.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really legal code. `foo()` is marked `restrict(amp)` which means it can only run inside a C++AMP kernel.  Functions marked `restrict(amp)` can only be called from code running on an acceleration, in other words from within a `parallel_for_each` lambda that is also `restrict(amp)`

```
void foo() restrict(amp)
{
}

void main() 
{
    parallel_for_each(e, [=](index<2> idx) restrict(amp)
    {
       foo()
    });
}
```

If you marked `foo()` as `restrict(amp,cpu)` then you could also call it from the CPU, provided the code inside `foo()` met the requirements for both AMP and CPU code.